# In Flutter, when using Box Decoration, why is BorderRadiusGeometry listed as parameter type for borderRadius:?

Tags: flutter, border, box, decoration

I am using the BoxDecoration widget, and next to the borderRadius: parameter, android studio tells me the type is meant to be BorderRadiusGeometry. When I attempt to fill in BorderRadiusGeometry I get this error:

> "The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'BorderRadiusGeometry?'"

```
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadiusGeometry)
```

Instead, I must use BorderRadius

```
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 2),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)))
```

why does the documentation list BorderRadiusGeometry as the parameter type?

I was expecting that the parameter would be inside the BorderRadiusGeometry, something like
BorderRadiusGeometry.all(5)

Answer (score 0):

- When you see '**`BorderRadiusGeometry`**' listed as the parameter type in the documentation, it means that you can pass any subclass of BorderRadiusGeometry to the '**`borderRadius`**' parameter of the BoxDecoration widget. However, ' **you cannot directly assign the BorderRadiusGeometry** ' class itself to the borderRadius parameter because it's an **`abstract class`**.
- To provide a concrete implementation of BorderRadiusGeometry, you need to use one of its subclasses, such as BorderRadius. In your case, you're using ' `const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))` ', which creates a BorderRadius object with a circular border radius of 5. This is the correct way to define the rounded corners for your BoxDecoration.
- So, in summary, **`BorderRadiusGeometry`** is a base class, and you need to use its concrete subclasses like BorderRadius to provide actual border radius values.

[Check Flutter Documentation Here !!](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadiusGeometry-class.html#:%7E:text=BorderRadiusGeometry%20class%20abstract,and%20its%20variants%2C%20or%20BorderRadiusDirectional.)